# Authentication failed for iOS app-specific password, but what do I do with my app-specific password? Where does it go?

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store

Got a new SSD for my mac (so it is like starting over), and am trying to set it up for Xamarin iOS development (again). After much fun with Apple procedures I am ready to upload to the App store, but get this message:

[image]

This message pops up when I am after the Archive is built, after I select Upload (after Sign and Distribute). It seems the important part is **Authentication failed Sign in with the app-specific password you generated.**

Sign in? Sign in to what? I have my app specific password, but what do I do with it?

There certainly seems to be a lot of web pages trying to push me to appcenter.ms, but I should not be forced to use a Microsoft service to distribute my app and do not wish to go that route at this time.

---

**Below are some hints to help others** who like me are not full time iOS app developers and are tired of massive web pages explaining the process.

Important things to know/remember for Xamarin/iOS development (obviously you need a Apple developer account, need to install XCode, VS, Xamarin):

- you need to tell XCode your Apple developer credentials
- you need to tell VS your Apple developer credentials
- you need to tell Apple the UID of your build box, test devices
- you need a developer certificate and distribution certificate from Apple
- you need to create two provisioning profiles, one for development and one for distribution
- somehow building a Xamarin iOS demonstration project in VS on my Mac made the iOS simulators available to other projects
- you may need a special Apple intermediate certificate (AppleWWDRCAG3.cer) and install it, even though various webpages said that was only necessary if your XCode was an old version (I had the latest XCode and still had to find/install it)

Comment: what are you doing that generates this error?  Compiling?  Uploading to the App Store with Transporter?

Comment: after the Archive is built, after I select Upload

Comment: I may be out of date.  There used to be a standalone app for uploading the binary, now it looks like its integrated into XCode and VS

Comment: This Transporter app seems promising, now have to get past a new error that my build supports fewer devices, and that is a big no-no according to Apple

Comment: After upgrading my target build to iOS 13 (and messing around with other build settings) Transporter finally succeeded in uploading my app to appstoreconnect.apple.com and now my app is in review. yay. It only took 3/4 days to submit.

Comment: Apple has marked my app as Invalid Binary, great

Comment: Just to be clear, the "Upload" option from Visual Studio archive process never worked, gave up on it. Instead save to disk and use Apple's Transporter. Also, my app has been in Review for a couple days, so seems like things should be okay, knock on wood